# How to access Intellisense for Excel API 1.7 from Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I have a custom web Visual Studio 2017 project in which I would like to access Excel API 1.7. How do I do it? What files should I include through CDN or for Offline use?

If I use NuGet for Microsoft.Office.js, then I get Excel API 1.1 only. Intellisense shows Excel API 1.1. Cannot make use of Excel API 1.7?

I am not able to access gridlines property on Worksheet object. Refer https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheet